# i tried to Apply check All to my form but not effected

Tags: asp-classic

I tried to Apply check All to some inputs with radio type but not working and I don't know why ?

I tried this as input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all" value="1"
                onclick='
    <%
    xox=0
    while xox<count
        xox=xox+1
        %>
        Radio1_<%=xox%>.checked=true;
    <%wend%>
                                '
                                >ApplyAll


        <td class="style13" style="width: 75">
        <input class="style15" name="Radio1_<%=count%>" type="radio" value="0"
         onclick='
 AdminDet<%=count%>.disabled=true;
 AdminDet<%=count%>.value="";
 if (Radio1_<%=count%>.checked==true)
     Radio1_<%=count%>.checked=false;
 else
     Radio1_<%=count%>.checked=true;
 '><span class="style16">Accept</span></td>
```

Comment: Classic ASP (VBScript) = Server side code (executed before pageload).  JavaScript OnClick = Client side code.   You can't use a client side code to run server side code that way (except by causing either a post or reload of the page).  You will want to use JavaScript code to check all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
    I= record count of total radio
    %>
        <FORM class=niceform method="GET" action="anketilet.asp" name="anketform"  onsubmit="return z();">  


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function z()
    {
        var de='<%=I%>';
        var z=0;
        for (i=0;i<anketform.elements.length ; i++ ) {
            if (anketform.elements[i].type == 'radio'/* && anketform.elements[i].checked*/) 
            {
                if(anketform.elements[i].checked)
                    {
                    z++;
                    }          
            }
              }

         if (z!=de)
            {
                alert("Lütfen cevapları eksiksiz doldurduğunuzdan emin olunuz!...");
                return (false);
            }
         else return (true);


    }

    </script>
    </table>

    </fieldset><br>
       <fieldset class="action" style="width: 800px;">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="GÖNDER">
        </fieldset></FORM>
```